# collection sorting/enumeration bug: too many entries in my sorted list

Tags: java, collections

The issue is that i get extra 2 elements in `listOf_sorted_APPFiles` from somewhere.

```
    Map<String, List<APPfile>> APPfilesMapByFileName 
            = new HashMap<String, List<APPfile>>();

       ...

    Collections.sort(fileNames, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
    logger.debug("Sorted count " + fileNames.size()); // 77

    // There will always be a list. Most of the time it will contains 
    // 1 element, but sometimes it may contains more

    for (String sortedFileName : fileNames) {
        for (APPfile a: APPfilesMapByFileName.get(sortedFileName)) {
               listOf_sorted_APPFiles.add(a);
        }
    }

    logger.debug("listOf_sorted_APPfiles count: " + 
                listOf_sorted_APPfiles.size()); // 79
       ...
```

I expect counts of `listOf_sorted_APPFiles` and `fileNames` to match, yet somehow i get extra 2 elements. Elements that are added extra are the ones coming from lists that contain more then one element.

Comment: How is listOf_sorted_APPFiles initialized?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @DanDaviesBrackett, yes to `new ArrayList<APPfile>`

Comment: While I applaud the community for it's effort to help individuals, in the long run, these sorts of questions have no long term value on this site and just create useless clutter. If a common problem is presented, it's a different matter, but problem's of "spot the mistake and get some easy reputation" are bad for the site imo.

Comment: @TimGee This is not a search for reputation, but i agree, the questions is too localized. I flagged it myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two nested "for". So, if sometimes there happen more than one element of APPfilesMapByFileName with the same filename, you MUST have more output elements.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you add all elements, including multiple `APPfile` so the count differs but result of your code is expected. Please, give more details about the problem you solve

Comment: A HashMap contains 1 unique "file". For that "file" we have a list of Objects. Whatever is in that list should only be added once, as "file" is looped through only once. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, how about making `listOf_sorted_APPFiles` a `TreeSet`? it will preserve sorted order and there won't be duplicates